# CORS issue: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" has a value that does not match the request origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, cors

I'm facing an issue with CORS when trying to make a request from my website to another server. I'm using JavaScript and fetch to send the request. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
fetch('https://devapi.madgs.ru/get-user-data', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include'
}).then(response => {
  // Response handling
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

However, when I make this request, I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://dev.madgs.ru/' (redirected from 'https://devapi.madgs.ru/get-user-data') from origin 'https://dev.madgs.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

also, I’m posting the code that I use in the backend part:

```js
const https = require('https'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      cors = require('cors'),


app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://dev.madgs.ru',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://dev.madgs.ru"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    next();
  });

server.listen(config.port, () => {
    config.domain
    console.log(`Listen server ${config.hostname}:${config.port}`);
});
```

I don't have access to the server I'm requesting to in order to change the CORS headers. How can I solve this issue? Can I use the no-cors request mode? And how will it affect my requests and security?

Comment: *note* get requests work well, only post does not work

Comment: The error message suggest to use `no-cors`, have a try `mode: 'no-cors'` and see what's happen

Comment: nothing will happen, the request will be sent, but I won’t be able to receive the data, and this is very important

Comment: The error says: If the wildcard parameter (`*`) is used, you cannot use `use-credentials', so try by removing the `credentials: 'include'` since your server already allows any origin to access this data, regardless of credentials.